# Angular get param of parent route in child route works only on the one with empty path

Tags: angular, routes

I have a strange issue where I have the following route setup:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ANiceComponent, children: [
    { path: 'someurl/:id', component: AnOtherComponent, canActivate: [UserSignedInGuard], children: [
      { path: 'something', component: ASubComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '', component: AMainSubPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]}
  ]}
];
```

In the `AMainSubPageComponent` I can access the `id` param. In the `ASubComponent` I am not able to access the `id` param. I have tried changeing the path `'something'` to `''` and the other way around. With this I know now that the empty path works but the not empty one doesnt work.

I am accessing the route in the same way and ensured that im not missing anything and doing it in the same way. The test (where I changed the path for testing) has also show that this is caused by a not empty path. This is the way I am accessing the params:

```
this.routeSub = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map(params => {
        console.log(params);
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

Am I missing something?
Sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the [parent](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#parent) of an active route to get access to the parent parameters.

```js
this.routeSub = this.route.parent.paramMap.pipe(
      map(params => {
        console.log(params);
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. Is it intended to use parent for this purpose or should it work also without? Im just wondering why this works on the route with empty path but not on the one with a path

Comment: @NeXuS a parent and child can have a parameter of the same name. So that is why they are separate (so there is no collision). What I do is take the parameter in the parent and put it into a shared service as an observable. This makes it easier to change your routing later without having to find where the paramMap is used around the app.